# Xamarin Android deployment not using the latest code?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.android, apk, xamarin.forms

I'm creating an Android app in Visual Studio. When I create the aligned APK to side load on my device (from the Tools -> Android -> Publish Android App), it installs and runs, but doesn't seem to have the very latest changes. The series of events I've experienced is as follows:

- Installed a version of the app on my device
- Updated a color on the login page and set the application theme (among other things)
- Re-installed the app
- Saw the new theme but not the new color on the login page
- Made a random text change on the login page as a test
- Re-installed the app
- Saw the color change but not the random text change?!

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: To ensure you're running the latest version, clean the project first :/ No idea really, might just be a weird mishap.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced similar issues, my go to for fixing this issue has been the following

- Clean all projects.
- Build all projects (especially the project containing the xcml files).
- Delete (remove application) from the device.

If for some reason this doesn't solve the problem, typically a full restart of Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio does.

Comment: This worked for me in Xamarin Forms. It happened to me after I pulled someone else's commit with different settings I'm guessing.

Comment: Deleting the application from the device is a fix but not always viable when you are sending stuff into the field. I had this problem in tech support whilst working at Realm - one of our Xamarin SDK users had an app in the field which was not updating.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a similar problem with connected device, and no one proposed solution like Clean\Rebuild\Restart\Reinstall\etc could help me.
At the same time on the AVD everything worked perfectly, latest code deployed ok.

I found that asked issue depended on selected settings in the [USB Developer] section on the connected device (mine was **Xiaomi** smartphone). Because some vendors provide us with too many security settings...

What I found, you have to **turn on** both **USB Debugging** & **USB debugging (Security settings)**, and **[turn off MIUI Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239251/install-failed-user-restricted-android-studio-using-redmi-4-device)** (it's true for Xiaomi vendor, but you can check your device for similar options). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar weird problem where old code from **only a single project** doesn't get updated.  All other projects do get updated/deployed.  It only happens on a single emulator, only in Debug mode, and only for that one project.

Cleaning+rebuilding the entire solution did not work.  However, **telling VS to rebuild the individual project does**.

Why doesn't rebuilding the solution rebuild the project?  I have no freakin' clue, but I can consistently reproduce this issue and workaround.