# Error occurring while connecting to redminote4

Tags: java, php, android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVTe6.png)

Installation failed with message `INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED: Install canceled by user`.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

> WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!
>
> Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSTALL\_FAILED\_USER\_RESTRICTED : android studio using redmi 4 device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239251/install-failed-user-restricted-android-studio-using-redmi-4-device)