# why visual studio does not detect my external device with xamarin?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I want to run my application in visual studio 2015 with a Xiaomi redmi note 4 device, but it does not show it to me in the toolbar.

I have the developer mode activated and the debug mode activated in the same way, but the device does not appear.

[image]

Comment: Try restarting the adb server (`adb kill-server; adb start-server`). If that does not work, does Android Studio see the device? If not it could be you do not have the proper device driver installed. The MI PC Suite contains the USB driver: http://pcsuite.mi.com

Answer (score 0):

you need to :

1- install the adp driver to detect you external device in visual studio nav-bar

2-switch your android to mode developper .

watch this video :
            https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uszn-sHh88o

Answer (score 0):

[I use this and works now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48524656/1661562)

Steps for MIUI 9 and Above:

Settings -> Additional Settings -> Developer options ->

1. Turn off "MIUI optimization" and Restart
2. Turn On "USB Debugging"
3. Turn On "Install via USB"
4. Set USB Configuration to Charging
5. Turn On "install via USB

MTP(Media Transfer Protocol) is the default mode.
Works even in MTP in some cases