# When I am trying to install APK file in my device they shows error

Tags: android-studio

When I am trying to run my android studio program in my device which is connected with USB, It show an error msg:

> **Installation failed with message Failed to commit install session 482678384 with command cmd package install-commit 482678384. Error: INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED: Install canceled by user.
>   It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.
>   )**

I tried all possible methods but at the end I am not able run my code.

Comment: pls help to resolve this problem

Comment: Have you tried what the error message suggests? `It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSTALL\_FAILED\_USER\_RESTRICTED : android studio using redmi 4 device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239251/install-failed-user-restricted-android-studio-using-redmi-4-device)