# INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED Installation via USB is disabled

Tags: android, android-studio, launching-application

09/18 11:00:20: Launching 'app' on Xiaomi Redmi 6.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED
Installation via USB is disabled.

Comment: Is your developer's option is turned on? If not, please turn on developers option. Allow installs from an unverified source. Its all in the security settings of Android.

Answer (score 3):

Try turning off MIUI optimization (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48524656/80901). This helped me with a Redmi.

Comment: This worked for me on Xiaomi Redmi Note 4

Answer (score 2):

If anyone trying in MI Phones and no other option for him his there, As Turning off MIUI optimization decrease the battery performance. Then he can try cleaning data of Security app.

Note- This can once ask your pattern lock after doing it. After that it will work fine.

Comment: On a Xiaomi Redmi Note 5, going to Apps, finding Security App, then deleting data and cache worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

> Please Turn on "USB debugging" in developer options. Additionally you also have to turn on "Install Apps via USB".. Hopefully it will work smoothly.

Comment: USB Debugging is ON

Comment: You are right in android 10 we have to enable additional setting which is allow installation via USB

Answer (score 0):

Turn on USB debugging in Developer option and when you connect your device to PC via USB a popup will appear, please check allow "USB Debugging" Option, and your app will be installed without error.

Comment: USB Debugging is ON

Comment: Have turned on installapp via usb checkbox, you can see the option in same screen as USB Debugging button

Answer (score 0):

I have Xiaomi **Redmi 4**, so hope it is relevant to Redmi 6.
When trying to install via USB, the device will ask you to enter via your MI account and if you not have one so create it and then Installation via USB should work.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Developer option and turn on "Install via USB" option which is below of "USB debugging" option.

Answer (score 0):

Run "adb uninstall " and it solves the problem.
It occurs when you uninstall manuelly an app which is build by Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed `Background process limit` in Developer Options to `No background process`. The same error will also occur.

If you did, change `Background process limit` back to `Standard limit`

Answer (score 0):

For those who working with knox container try:
AndroidStudio -> Run -> Edit Configurations -> [select] : Install for all users.