# react-native run android build failed

Tags: react-native

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app: install Debug'.

  > com .android. builder. testing. a pi. Device Exception: com. android . Install Exception: INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED: Install can c e led by user
- Try:
  Run with --stack trace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 0s

```
at check Exec Sync Error (child_process.js:629:11)
at exec File Sync (child_process.js:647:13)
at run On All Devices (C:\Users\dell\Desktop\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\run Android\runOnAllDevices.js:74:39)
at build And Run (C:\Users\dell\Desktop\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\run Android\index.js:158:41)
at then . result (C:\Users\dell\Desktop\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12)
at process . _ tick Call back (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: at the time of react-native run-android I found the error build failed..what  I do pls help....

Comment: You have redmi note device? If yes, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239251/install-failed-user-restricted-android-studio-using-redmi-4-device