# Android Studio error "Installation failed due to: 'Connection refused: connect'"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, connection, launch

I am trying to install the app but Android Studio showing error:

```
Launching 'app' on Xiaomi Redmi 4A.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.
...
Installation failed due to: 'Connection refused: connect'
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: have you tried solutions from this thread.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239251/install-failed-user-restricted-android-studio-using-redmi-4-device

Comment: can you  add full log  error image?

Comment: @TalhaAhmed Try them why? What do user permissions have to do with 'connection refused'?

Answer (score 7):

If this happened on Android Emulator you can simply:

- **Clean Project**

then

- **Rebuild Project**

[image]

Comment: I came for a solution to my problem.... and this one helped me alot !

Comment: Simple and correct!

Answer (score 1):

Steps for MIUI 9 and Above:

Settings -> Additional Settings -> Developer Options -> Enable USB Debugging, Enable Install via USB , Enable USB Debugging(Security Settings)

Turn off "MIUI optimization" and Restart

Turn On "USB Debugging"

Turn On "Install via USB"

Set USB Configuration to Charging

MTP(Media Transfer Protocol) is the default mode.
Works even in MTP in some cases

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred because your system settings disabled proxy and you build android project using proxy event. You don't know that you're enabling proxy to find out most of people go to `android -> gradle.properties` this is right but you need to check on your system pc's `gradle.properties` file. I'm using a mac, so in my case this file is in `mypc/.gradle/gradle.properties`. In this file you can remove proxy related code.

This solution worked for me and maybe it works for you as well!