# INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED: Install canceled by user install apps via adb (no Sim Card)

Tags: android, adb, android-10.0

I am trying to install an app on my Android device via `adb` and this error appears all the time.

My device does **NOT** have a sim card, so I cannot activate `install via usb` or `usb debugging security setting`.

Worth mentioning:

-`usb debugging` is on and device model is Redmi Note8 Pro.

-installing via `adb` was working well and the issue appears after the recent device factory reset.

Comment: Maybe the signature of apk is different, if apk is installed already, did you tried uninstalling it

Comment: There is no app installed on the device, has been recently factory reset.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [INSTALL\_FAILED\_USER\_RESTRICTED : android studio using redmi 4 device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239251/install-failed-user-restricted-android-studio-using-redmi-4-device)

Comment: No.
I made `NOT` bold to differentiate my question and the one you are referring. I have read the other one and did not find my answer there. Please reopen the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Insert a sim, enable Install via USB and remove the sim.
Toggle will remain switched on even after removing the sim.