# Error: ADB exited with exit code 1 - remedy?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to debug a demo app of flutter in vscode where the error is showing for ADB exit with code 1
performing streamed install. I uninstall the existing Flutter demo app.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [how-to-ask article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. Espc. do not post screen-shots of code etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with these three stuff:

1. Check out if your emulator memory full.
2. Check your package name is alright
3. Clean your flutter and re-run

flutter clean

flutter run

Comment: clean your flutter and re-run?? can u explain me this please?? actually new here.

Comment: you should run it from VSCODE terminal

Comment: running from there only.

Comment: first clean then run

Comment: thats i am asking how i can clean it.

Comment: Error: ADB exited with exit code 1 Performing Streamed Install adb: failed to install C:\flutter project\first project\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED: Install canceled by user] Error launching application on Redmi 5.

Comment: make sure the developer option and your USB is enabled. If your developer mode is off then you should follow this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239251/install-failed-user-restricted-android-studio-using-redmi-4-device

Comment: its is enabled.

Comment: can you please share me our number if u don't mind

Comment: there will be another option called install over USB in developer options. check u enabled it . few devices have it 

for the first time when we are using usb debugging we have press allow on the device

Answer (score 0):

as APK built is Successful there is no issue with the code.
there is something wrong with the device

check u enabled USB debugging
check u enabled install over USB in developer option

few devices don't have to enable install over USB.

then

```
flutter clean && flutter pub get
```

uninstall the app in the device and run

```
flutter run -d <device name>
```

*emphasized text*