# Can't Debug Android Application on my Phone

Tags: android, android-studio, development-environment, xiaomi, miui

Recently I tried to debug an application on my phone but I found this error :

**`Installation did not succeed.`**

**`The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED`**

I tried the following :

1. Disable **USB Debugging** and Re-Enable it.
2. Disable **MIUI Optimization** and Re-Enable it.
3. **Restart** my phone.

The Problem still exists. I need some help.

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: There are also some more options suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239251/install-failed-user-restricted-android-studio-using-redmi-4-device). Can you give them a try?

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work

Comment: Disable & re-enable usb debugging option in your phone while its connected with your pc. When enabling your phone will show a prompt asking to allow the pc to debug. Allow it. Also at the time of first installtion your phone will ask for confirmation to install the app.

Answer (score 0):

Please check all this configuration in your device before you run your app into your physical android device

- Enable `Unknown sources` toggle in settings so it will allow you to install apk which are not downloaded from google playstore
- Enable `USB Debugging` toggle in settings which will allow you to install and debug by USB

once done unplug device and plug again so it may ask you for sha key confirmation which you need to confirm on plugin device

after that try to run app on your device , which will show you small dialog with timer of 10 seconds to allow to install .. if you miss it then it will automatically reject and show you error that you are facing

Answer (score 0):

Make sure following options is enabled

1. Force full GNSS measurement.
2. USB debugging.
3. Install via USB.
4. USB debugging.

It works for me.